# How did this member get a reputation of 8 from 4 upvotes and 11 downvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation

In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39216/why-are-we-talking-about-space-curvature-as-if-we-know-what-space-is)  there are eleven downvotes. I know from downvotes I have gotten that each downvote subtracts 2 points. 2x11=22 should be deleted. The user has a remainder of 8. How is this possible? Even if he/she came with the dowry of 100 from another site, still 8 is not what it should be:78 is not 8. Is there another rule?

Comment: 'dowry of 100 from another site'- Wow! I never thought they are dowry; well, then it is illegal in our country to have dowry:P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I look at his reputation log:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12803/thomas-an?tab=reputation&sort=post

I see reputation-altering events that add up +35 (7 upvotes) and -28 (mostly downvotes, but also a couple "user was removed."

Add in the +1 for what the user presumably started at, and it makes sense.

I think the "rule" you're forgetting is that rep can't go below 1, so when you look at his first day, he started at 1, got 1 upvote (+5) and 6 downvotes.  But the first 4 of those downvotes didn't count against him because rep can't go below 1 and they came before he got any upvotes.

I think that also applies to the -1 showing for a downvote the next day: he only had 2 rep, that downvote only cost him 1.

Comment: I did not know one could look at the reputation log and had forgotten that one cannot go below zero. thanks